# Value error, image normalization error using VGG16, face recognition and detection project

Tags: python, image-processing, normalization, face-recognition, valueerror

[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTI8f.jpg)

I am working on a face detection and recognition project. VGG16 was used and during training, the images (array) were normalized (images= images.astype('float32')/255).

The same thing is done during face detection on the frames (from the video) but I am getting a value error as the input shape is changed. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHpae.jpg) However, the image shape was printed and it is 150,150,3, why is the error occurring?

Is this because a list of images has to be normalized and a single image will not work? If so, is there any better way of fixing the error and successfully using the model to predict the image?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by reshaping the image by doing the following command below.
Image = tf.reshape(image, [1,150, 150,3])